# Change variable if a certain substring has been found (via for loop)

Tags: r, for-loop, substr

I would like to change the "variable" to 1, if x contains 4.
  This code that I have written seems not to work because after
  executing it the variable is still zero. I tried to include `"print (i)"`
  to see whether the for loop gets to the "4" in x, but only "1" was
  printed. So the for-loop seems not to make more than one run....
  Could someone tell what's wrong with this code?

```
 x=22356478998
    variable=0
    for(i in 1:length(x)){
    if( substr(x,start=i,stop=i)=="4"){
      variable=1
      break
    }
    }
```

Comment: Use `nchar` not `length`

Comment: Thanks Frank, the simple replacement "nchar" worked!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `grepl` (it's in `base`)

```
variable = as.integer(grepl("4", x))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `str_detect()` from the `stringr` package:

```
library(stringr)
x=22356478998
variable <- ifelse(str_detect(x, "4"), 1, 0)
```

Comment: Nice, but integers like 1L and 0L are better than floats for a binary variable. You can do `as.integer(str_detect(x, "4"))` or similar with `grepl`.